# What do you think of Copper's name field solution?

Tags: forms, progressive-disclosure

I am have been searching across several CRMs and I have not come across anyone who does the single name field as Copper does. I think it is brilliant and it can solve a situation in a design I am currently working on. There are no reviews (that I have seen) for this implementation. What does the UX community think here? Benefits vs drawbacks.

[image] 
[image: revised Copper's solution]

Playing around to see about the label. What do you think now?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/36scy.jpg

Comment: Can you navigate with the keyboard? or do you have to click on each field?

Comment: I'd be very curious to know what that interaction sounds like to a screen reader user.

Comment: How editing of a Name will look like where placeholder tips are not visible? Editing is usually the same form with adding new instance will you keep editing as shown? If no then adding should match editing.

Comment: What is your *specific* question here? Pros/Cons question don't really work well on a site such as this where we can only give a single answer. Is there a specific situation you are wanting to use this in?

Comment: Names can be tricky. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that possible drawbacks could be:

- The time required to fill all of the different fields will be longer than a single one and can thus cause frustration in the user;
- The least tech-savy users could find it difficult to understand that they need to click away to fill the rest of the form, or at least feel "lost" when they see the rest being hidden.

Comment: I think the second point is the most damning. Visually I find the form appealing - I like it. But we're designing for others. Unless you're designing for a tech savvy community I would avoid it.

Comment: @StarGirl What if we added below options DONE and CANCEL? SO the actively click done when they have edited relevant fields?

Comment: Adding submit button will increase the click count even more. I will not recommend this pattern either, there is a lot of compromise in terms of usability.

Comment: I agree with @Ren, that would slow down the user + confuse the user on whether they are clicking DONE for the whole form. In that case, it would be more linear to make a wizard but then you end up adding a new step for the name alone

Answer (score 0):

The interface makes users do work that the program should be doing (parsing the fields). For difficult names, there can be an optional toggle that will open up the separate fields with the software's best-attempt. Otherwise, **it's a bait-and-switch.** Users are expecting to fill out a single field, but at the last moment, it's swapped out for a half-dozen separate fields that have to be filled out separately. It might *not* be "slower", but it is more tedious.

Imagine the answer boxes on this site splitting up into a bunch of different fields for each sentence when users click on them. *Someone* somewhere might like the new interface, but I wouldn't expect it to be many.